# Excel: Return all matches in columns using one criteria (from drop down)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I am having two tables, one table is main data, separated into many columns and blocks per 10 rows in one, this is fixed. In Column A are unique numbers that will be used in drop down.

Table 1

[image: Table 1]

On second table is a report or printing sheet where I would like to have all infos from table 1 when choosing from drop down list from Column A2. To populate all matches, starting from Column B, no matter if there are couple matches or if it is complete, means there are blanks too, but withing those blocks of 10 rows.

Table 2
[image: Table 2]

I have been using this formula but I am not getting proper result, or it matches only for first row and rest is or repetative or error.

```
=INDEX(Table1[Datum];SMALL(IF(Table1[Nummer]=Printable!$A$2;ROW(Table1[Nummer])-ROW(INDEX(Table1[Nummer];1;1))+1);1))
```

**Data added!**

Normal vlookup is also starting point but I got lost with everything and simply cant get all required matches..

```
Number  Date        Signature  1. Problem   2. Description  3. System
ÄM11_1  01.01.2021  MV         Alarm ON     Alarm OFF       0528
        01.02.2021  AB         N/A          N/A             0347
        10.02.2021  CD         Pressuure H! Valve           0321

... this is for one unique number (column A), ten rows are per one block (same as on screenshot divided with line)...doesn't have to be full but must be 10 rows!
```

**Edited!**
Output should be something like this...colored field is drop down, and when I choose something from it, all fields should be updated with the data from main table...everything at once.

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you paste (some of) the table data, which is text in the first place, as text and not as a screenshot?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke From main data table or?

Comment: I don't know, you're best to judge that. Something small that answerers can use to reproduce your issue and provide a solution.

Comment: It would also help if you show what the intended result is, e.g. by manually creating a small version (i.e. 5 rows) of your desired resulting table.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke  I added some values....well think of it as lookup values that have to populated from one big table with unique values, to match all what it finds depending on drop down.

Comment: So bear with me. What data did you include? Is that how it should look like in the end?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke  no it is not, i told you, the data is like from table 1 , where the data is divided in block depending on unique numbers. Every block has some Infos, but same structure.. but the list is super long so I cant copy all, because it is same concept of data as I wrote up. So you can imagine clicking one drop down and getting those lists updated without scrolling endlessly through columns and rows.

Comment: "So you can imagine clicking one drop down and getting those lists updated without scrolling endlessly through columns and rows" Is that your goal? I could not know that, it's not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

As you goal seems to be to easily access a set of rows based on the "Number" column (without having to scroll), I think using tables with a filter is the most convenient:

[image: Final result of filtering table]

To achieve above result you first need to make sure that the "Number" value appears in every row. You can do that with the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(B2), A1, B2)`:

[image]

Then copy column A and paste it in place, but paste it as values:

[image]

Now you can safely delete column B (where only every 10 rows the number is written).

Last thing to do is to select all rows (including the header) and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. This creates a table out of it, allowing you to easily filter.

Comment: Hmm interesting approach, but what if I have more tables beneath? I am saying this because I just saw that it might be possible to have many columns that can't fit on regular printed sheet, so the table must be cut down into half or more. That means I can have more excel tables but I might loose filter for other not connected tables...if you understand what I am saying. I wrote above "printing sheet" but page has to be like in a new screenshot I uploaded....

Comment: You could create multiple, separate tables below each other, and only filter the top one.

Answer (score 0):

The point is drop-down list works when all entries of say AM11_1, must be repeated down the column. Then only it works for that many rows.